# spring security custom login method post not supported

Tags: spring, security, post, spring-security

I am adopting spring security into my little project.
I have a problem that when I try to submit a form with POST method to login, spring security HTTP 405 error(POST not supported) is raised.

Here is my code below.

Spring Security AppContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mybatis-spring="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring-1.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">


    <http security="none" pattern="/resources/**" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/home/testpage" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/user/join-form" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/user/join" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/user/activate-user" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/user/login-form" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/user/check-duplication-email" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/user/check-duplication-nickname" />


    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/home/main" access="permitAll"/>

        <form-login 
            login-page="/user/login-form" 
            default-target-url="/home/main"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
            username-parameter="email"
            password-parameter="passwd"
            login-processing-url="/user/login"
        />

        <csrf/>

        <logout
            logout-url="/user/logout"
            invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/user/login-form"
        />

        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/" />
        </session-management>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:beans profile="common">
        <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.winsplay.whiteboard.web.auth.CustomAuthenticationProvider" >
            <beans:property name="userSecurityService" ref="userSecurityService" />
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="com.winsplay.whiteboard.web.auth.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler" />

        <beans:bean id="userSecurityService" class="com.winsplay.whiteboard.web.auth.UserSecurityServiceImpl" />
        <mybatis-spring:scan base-package="com.winsplay.whiteboard.web.auth" annotation="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
    </beans:beans>

</beans:beans>
```

JSP Login form:

```
<c:if test="${anonymous}">
    <div id="login-popup">
        <p class="info">login</p>

        <hr />



            <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/login" method="post">
                <sec:csrfInput/>
                <p><form:errors /></p>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right;"><p class="input-header">email</p></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="email" class="myinput" name="email" placeholder="abc@abc.com" />
                            </td>
                            <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:top;">
                                <input type="image" style="position:relative; top:-10px;" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/btn_login.JPG" alt="btn_login" title="login" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td style="text-align:right;"><p class="input-header">password</p></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="password" class="myinput" name="passwd" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div style="text-align:right; margin-right:100px; margin-top:30px;">
                    <a class="my-btn" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/find-password">find password</a>
                    <a class="my-btn close-lightbox" href="#">close</a>             
                </div>

            </form:form>





        <hr />
    </div>
</c:if>
```

How do I send POST method to login?

Thanks in advance.

<http security ="none" ... > thingy is for debugging

Comment: this could be happening because you need to pass the CSRF token in your login.jsp form. try adding  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" /> within your form tags

Comment: <sec:csrfInput/> is the same with <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />, and it doesn't work. I can check csrf token set well when I go into my web site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

POST not supported problem was came from AuthenticationFailureHandler which calls "setUseForward(true)" in my code.

Firstly, I delivered wrong password parameter to service layer, and it returns false, making throwing BadCredentialException. And the exception is forwarding to AuthenticationFailureHandler. Since I customized the class, I called "setUseForward(true)" which forwards request with POST method, and the controller holding the URL did not accept POST method.

Below code was an actual reason.

```
@RequestMapping("...", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your security setting, you should change this :

```
login-processing-url="/user/login"
```

to this :

`login-processing-url="/login"`   or   `login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"`

and change your login form action to this :

`/login`  or `/j_spring_security_check` depend on your setting.

This happen because spring cannot find the Token Processing Filter, if you change that, then spring will go directly to your `CustomAuthenticationProvider`

p/s : If your form cannot find the action url, you can use the `c` or `spring` tag library.

Comment: No, login-processing-url works fine with "/user/login". Besides, I solved this issue. check my answer please.